# Quantify/visualize atomic clusters in multi-component crystalline materials

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Let's say we have a material $AB$. Is it possible to detect atomic clusters of A atoms experimentally?

The size of clusters in question: 2 atoms (nearest neighbour (nn) pairs), 3 atoms (nn triangles), 4 atoms (nn tetrahedrons).

Comment: Crystalline or amorphous?

Comment: crystalline - ordered or disordered

Comment: EXAFS should be able to get you some info on nearest neighbor pairs populations. Not sure how to get to 3s or 4s though.

Comment: What is the smallest size of a cluster that can be detected? Is it about 20, 30, or more atoms?